# How to select a layer inside another layer in Photoshop with Javascript, and make it visible/invisible

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, extendscript

I have a Photoshop layer/smart object named "Culoare". When I double click on it, there is another list of layers/smart objects. I need to be able to make visible/invisible the layers inside the first layer. For example, make "warm white" invisible and "blue" visible.

[image: "Culoare" is the first object]
[image: I need to make visible or invisible the layers here]

My code so far:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var culoare = doc.layers[5];
doc.activeLayer = culoare;
culoare.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about photoshop script. But based on your code, it seems that the order of your last two lines should be:

```
culoare.visible = false; 
doc.activeLayer = culoare;
```

That is 'culoare' should not be visible before you assign it to the active layer. I dont understand why you would want it to be invisible if you are assigning it to the active layer though.

Comment: Well, its there because that's how I would make any layer visible or invisible. But how to select the layers inside of "culoare" and apply .visible to them?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there! You don't need to reference the culoare my the layer number as that may change. You can however, use the current active layer instead:

```
// Create a reference to the active document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Create a variable "culoare" as a reference to the current active layer
var culoare = doc.activeLayer;

// Make culoare visible if it's hidden
// or make culoare hidden if it's visible
culoare.visible = !culoare.visible;
```